# Jasper report Boolean

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a Boolean property in the domain object; so can be false, true or N/A if is null. I don't how could be the best option to represent it

```
<field name="isOSX" class="java.lang.Boolean">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[device.isOSX]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you can use that boolean value to print a text o draw a image, using for example the properties:

```
**Text field expression** in Text Fields
```

or

```
**Print When expression** in some other report elements.
```